# In what generality is the natural map $\textrm{Hom}_R(L,M)\otimes S \to \operatorname{Hom}_{R \otimes S}(L\otimes S, M \otimes S) $ an isomorphism?

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Note: A version of this question has been reposted to [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72004).

Let $k$ be a commutative ring, $R$ and $S$ commutative $k$-algebras.  Let $L$ and $M$ be $R$-modules.

Unless I am much mistaken, there is a natural map
$$\operatorname{Hom}_R(L,M)\otimes_k S \to \operatorname{Hom}_{R \otimes_k S}(L\otimes_k S, M \otimes_k S)$$
where $\phi \otimes s$ defines the $(R \otimes_k S)$-morphism
$$l \otimes s_1 \mapsto \phi(l) \otimes s s_1.$$
Based on a dimension count, I believe that this map is an isomorphism under sufficiently nice hypotheses.

> Under what hypotheses is this natural map an isomorphism?  In particular, do we need to assume that some or all of the modules are (locally) free and/or finitely generated?

I'm also going to take the liberty of throwing in an additional, more general question.  When I am trying to follow an argument that involves an unexplained "equality" of two expressions involving tensor product and/or Hom, I often find myself wanting to write down intermediate steps such as the one above, or the statement $$(M \otimes_k S) \otimes_{R \otimes_k S} (N \otimes_k R) = M \otimes_k N$$
for $M$ an $R$-module and $N$ an $S$-module.  In this situation, I tend to find myself thinking, "This looks familiar and plausible, and I can write down something on simple tensors that probably defines a natural map in at least one direction, but I can't remember for sure if this is actually an isomorphism under my hypotheses."  Is there a good "cheat sheet" (ideally a reference that is legally available online) for these sorts of things?

Answer (score 5):

Aaron and I were talking today and came up with a partial answer, as follows.

For simplicity, let $T$ denote $R \otimes_k S$.  The tensor-Hom adjunction (in a version that allows for change of rings) tells us that 
$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Hom}_T(L \otimes_k S, M \otimes_k S) 
& = \operatorname{Hom}_T(L \otimes_R T, M \otimes_k S) \\
& = \operatorname{Hom}_R(L, \operatorname{Hom}_T(T, M \otimes_k S)) \\
& = \operatorname{Hom}_R(L, M \otimes_k S).
\end{align*}$$
Now, we come to a hypothesis required for all the remaining reasoning: Namely, we assume that $S$ is free as a $k$-module.  (This is automatically true if $k$ is a field.) Thus, considering $S$ as a $k$-module, we write
$$S = \bigoplus_i k,$$ where $i$ ranges over some indexing set $I$.  Then, we have
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_R(L, M) \otimes_k S = \bigoplus_i \operatorname{Hom}_R(L, M)
$$
while
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_R(L, M \otimes_k S) = \operatorname{Hom}_R(L, \bigoplus_i M).
$$
If $L$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module, or if the direct sum is finite, then these two are naturally isomorphic. Thus, sufficient hypotheses to ensure an isomorphism are that $S$ is free over $k$ and either ($L$ is finitely generated over $R$) or ($S$ is finite over $k$).

On the other hand, if $L$ is not finitely generated, then the natural map need not be surjective.  For instance, if $L = \bigoplus_{j=1}^{\infty} R e_j$, $M = R$, and $i$ ranges over the integers, then we have
$$\begin{align*}
L & \to \bigoplus_i M e_i \\
e_j & \mapsto e_1 + \dotsb + e_j,
\end{align*}$$
a morphism that does not come from $\bigoplus_i \operatorname{Hom}_R(L, M)$.  So in this case, the map is *not* an isomorphism.

Comment: The counterexample appears to violate the accepted wisdom that "the map is an isomorphism if all modules in sight are free." Thus, I would appreciate it if people would point out any errors here.

Comment: The accepted wisdom was wrong.  If it wasn't, then we would have a cannonical isomorphism $\operatorname{End}(V)\cong V^{\star}\otimes V$ for all vector spaces $V$, (take $R=M=k, L=S=V$, where you have put an algebra structure on $S$).  The issue is that tensor products do not commute with direct products, even though they commute with direct sums.

Comment: @CharlesStaats, I think that has proved it for $S$ being free over $k$, one can very easily see that this gives us the identity when $S$ is also projective. I am mentioning this because when I came through this answer, I was in need for the projective case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks (to me) like this map is an isomorphism if $L$ is a free $R$-module.

Comment: Of course, I assume all modules finitely generated in the answer above.

Comment: ah right, my bad. I will delete the remark, the first sentence is still alright I think.