# Injectivity of derived Hom functor base change map

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, derived-functors, derived-categories, hom-functor

According to [Tag 0E1V](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0E1V) of Stacks, given a ring map $R \rightarrow R'$ and two $R$-modules $K,M$, there is a base change map
$$
R\mathop{\mathrm{Hom}}\nolimits _ R(K, M) \otimes _ R^\mathbf {L} R' \longrightarrow R\mathop{\mathrm{Hom}}\nolimits _{R'}(K \otimes _ R^\mathbf {L} R', M \otimes _ R^\mathbf {L} R').
$$
Lemma 15.97.2 [0A6A] gives some criteria for this map to be an isomorphism.
Are there any useful criteria for the map to be *injective*?

For example, with $R=M=\mathbb Z, K=R'=\mathbb Q$, it is not isomorphic, but it is injective ($0 \rightarrow \mathbb Q$).

**EDIT**
I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558705/b-is-a-flat-a-module-and-m-is-a-finitely-generated-a-module-then-%CF%83-operator?noredirect=1&lq=1) related question. But in the example above $\mathbb Q$ is not finitely generated as a module over $\mathbb Z$.