# Why is $\text{Hom}_S(k\otimes_R S, M\otimes_R N) \cong \text{Hom}_R(k,M) \otimes_R N$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, flatness

Here is the situation.

$\varphi: (R,\mathfrak{m},k) \to (S, \mathfrak{n},\ell)$ is a ring homomorphism. $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. $N$ is a finitely generated $S$-module and is flat over $R$.

I know there is a map $\Phi: \text{Hom}_R(k,M) \otimes_R N \to \text{Hom}_S(k\otimes_R S, M\otimes_R N)$ given by $f \otimes n \mapsto f\otimes (1_S \mapsto n)$, but how can I use the fact that $N$ is flat over $R$ and finitely generated to show that this is an isomorphism?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81429/hom-and-tensor-with-a-flat-module) could be helpful (at least to handle the left hand side). If you don't want to assume $R$ noetherian then notice that in the linked thread the isomorphism holds for $M$ finitely presented. This means that here we have to suppose $\mathfrak m$ finitely generated.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I fixed it.

Comment: Also, that link is useful. Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50699