# Is $\operatorname{Hom}(A\oplus B, C)=\operatorname{Hom}(A,C)\oplus\operatorname{Hom}(B,C)$? Where can I find general rules for $\operatorname{Hom}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, direct-sum, ring-homomorphism

Question is in the title. More specific, where can I find general calculation rules for $\operatorname{Hom},\otimes,\oplus$? I need them not very often, but if I need these rules, I can't find anything. Especially those things that seem simple, but are not trivial, are difficult for me.

In this case I want to calculate $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{C}^*)$ ($\mathbb{C}^*$ is the unit group). If I would have $\mathbb{Z}^2$ it would be easy and we would have $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^2,\mathbb{C}^*)=(\mathbb{C}^*)^2$ right? So is the result from the question just $\mathbb{C}^*\oplus\mathbb{C}^*$? Can I simplify this somehow? What exactly is the difference to $(\mathbb{C}^*)^2$?

Comment: For your specific question, $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{C}^*) \cong \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{C}^*) \oplus \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{C}^*) \cong \mathbb{C}^* \oplus \mathbb{C}^*$. The latter cannot be simplified, and is the same thing as $(\mathbb{C}^*)^2$.  $\oplus$ is called biproduct. It is a cartesian product, but we call it biproduct because it is simultaneously a product and a coproduct.

Comment: So we could also simplify $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ or is this conversion only valid for $\mathbb{C}^*$? You said its a cartesian product, but there is a difference between direct sum, tensor product and cartesian product, in this case it seems there is no difference. Why?

Comment: Good question. The Cartesian product construction matches the direct sum construction when there are finitely many summands. The proof is only one or two steps: by definition $\oplus_{i \in I} A_i = \{ (a_i)_{i \in I} : a_i \in A_i, \{ i \in I : a_i \neq 0 \} \text { is finite}  \}$ and $\prod_{i \in I} A_i =  \{ (a_i)_{i \in I} : a_i \in A_i \}$. If $I$ is finite, then $\{ i \in I : a_i \neq 0 \} \subset I$ is finite regardless of choice of $(a_i)_{i \in I}$. Therefore the two coincide.

Comment: Okay, then I wonder that in some literature where I stumbled over above calculation this $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ was explicitly stated and not $\mathbb{Z}^2$. But this was probably just for presentation purposes (like $...=\operatorname{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^1)\oplus\mathbb{Z}$). Thanks!

Comment: The two do not always match when $|I|$ is infinite. This marks the difference between the two constructions. Now, do not confuse either of these with tensor product, which is completely different. A good example to start with is vector spaces. Recall that a $k$-vector space is determined by its dimension (which is a cardinal). The dimension of the tensor product $V \otimes W$ has dimension $\text{dim}(V) \text{dim}(W)$. Direct sum has dimension $\text{dim}(V) + \text{dim}(W)$

Comment: When product matches coproduct (e.g. a vector space with objects resembling vector spaces), then $\oplus$ is preferred as notation, and suggests to the reader that coproduct matches product in this category. So instead of $\prod_{i \in I}$, $\oplus_{i \in I}$ is usually written. And instead of $(-)^n$, I personally always write $\oplus_{1 \leq i \leq n  } $. It is longer, but the notation reflects the property that finite coproducts are isomorphic to finite products (i.e. the situation in which we call these = this a biproduct).

Comment: A further recommendation is Keith Conrad's notes on tensor products, and other algebra, here https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true. The most common lemma that is used is that right adjoints preserve limits (if they are contravariant, then they send colimits to limits, and we still say that they are limit preserving - we always name things by the target).

Here, contravariant Hom is right adjoint, and so sends coproducts to products. It so happens that this category has biproducts, which are simulataneously products and coproducts. So it preserves them.

A text on category theory should have all of the necessary rules on Hom and tensor, except perhaps several interesting ones on how these relate to the finitely generated condition.

Here is a list of the four most common rules, which apply in a category with limits and colimits:

1. $\text{Hom}( \text{colim } X_i, Y) \cong \text{lim } \text{Hom}(X_i, Y)$.
2. In the case where the colimit is coproduct and the limit is product, we get $\text{Hom}(X \amalg Y, Z) \cong \text{Hom}(X, Z) \prod \text{Hom}(Y, Z)$
3. $\text{Hom}( X, \text{lim } Y_i) \cong \text{lim } \text{Hom}(X, Y_i)$.
4. The case where the limit is product above.

These four rules will give you most things you ever need. Further common results arise when something is required of one of the objects. Usually such situations reduce to one of the rules above, e.g.

5. $\text{Hom}_R(L, M ) \otimes S \stackrel{\cong}{\rightarrow} \text{Hom}_{R \otimes S} (L \otimes S, M \otimes S)$ The post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50699/in-what-generality-is-the-natural-map-textrmhom-rl-m-otimes-s-to-operato?rq=1) has sufficient conditions and a proof.

The post I linked to has links to other common ones, which might seem pretty fancy to a newcomer. The idea is just like you're thinking: bundle up the common results so that whenever you're working in XYZ category, you know the basics without having to think very much.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Do you know any literature where such general rules are clustered? Can one simplify $\mathbb{C}^*\oplus\mathbb{C}^*$ somehow?

Comment: Do you mean the dual vector space or the unit group in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: A good text on monoidal closed categories or tensor categories should have one, but I can't seem to find one right away... give me 5 min.

Comment: Say we've got the dual vector space $\mathbb{C}^* = \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}  \text{-vect}}(\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{C})$.  Then we use rule (2) above.

Comment: I meant the unit group - sorry, that wasn't clear, I edited that into the question

Comment: Then I just need to know more about categories especially limits and colimits. Are $\oplus,\otimes$ both, limits and colimits? Thanks for taking the time to write down some rules!

Comment: Colimits are a bit like gluing constructions. Like where you take a bunch of things and quotient by relations (at least, for categories which resemble "spacial" things). Limits can always be viewed as subsets of products (at least, when all limits exist) - subsets satisfying some rules. $\oplus$ is both a limit and a colimit. It is a product, which is a limit, and a coproduct, which is a colimit.

Comment: I think Emily Reihl's book is the best place to start, but it doesn't cover the monoidal closed setup where all this hom-stuff arises. If you ever want someone to help with your category, I love to talk about it with newcomers, so just email me at edeany@nyu.edu.

Comment: On further thought, the example you provided doesn't seem to have a convenient simplification, because $(-)^*$ is not related to $\oplus$ in the right way. $(-)^*$ here is $\text{GL}_1(-)$, and there's nothing really to do. What would work is if $(-)^*$ were the dual vector space of some vector space. The buzzword here is "monoidal closed category".

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate that! For now that's something I can work with, I surely will have a look into the book and into this topic. Thanks for being available for a talk as well!

Comment: Following up on other comments, esp. by @KindBubble, for very general categorical reasons, colimits are _quotients_ of coproducts, and limits are _subobjects_ of products (when everything exists...). Tensor-product-like things are sorta a level higher, often describable by the (Cartan-Eilenberg?) adjunction $\mathrm{Hom}(A\otimes B,C)\approx\mathrm{Hom}(A,\mathrm{Hom}(B,C))$...